# How to dynamically add prefixes to rows in a text file?

Tags: matlab, text, format

I have a very big text file, which has a format as follow:

> gene1 gene2
>
> gene3
>
> gene4
>
> gene5
>
> gene6
>
> gene7 gene8
>
> gene9
>
> ...

I want the format of this file like this:

> gene1    gene2
>
> gene1    gene3
>
> gene1    gene4
>
> gene1    gene5
>
> gene1    gene6
>
> gene7    gene8
>
> gene7    gene9
>
> ...

gene1, gene2, etc.. are some letter combinations without spaces that can have varying lengths.. An example file is below

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6u8fZadKIp2aEVIUTJ6NzlJVlk

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: please be more clear regarding what you want to achieve when you have multiple rows with 2 genes.. Do you want to keep the gene of the very first line in front of each row or do you want to continue repeating the new gene? See the edit I made to the question, do I understand you correctly?

Comment: the file in google drive is only 256 kb, cannot call that a big file. Is it only part of the whole file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% getting the text and the first word
text_in_file = fileread('oldfle.txt');
first_word = regexp(text_in_file, '\S*', 'match','once');

% generating the new string
str = regexprep(text_in_file,'[\n\r]+',['\n\n' first_word ' ']);
% writing to the file
fid = fopen('newfile.txt', 'wt');fprintf(fid, str);fclose(fid);
```

Here is a modified code that will deal with the case of many rows with 2 genes. It resets the count and starts inserting the new gene name in front of single gene rows. Is that what you wanted?

```
% getting the text
text_in_file = fileread('oldfile.txt');
% splitting into rows
rows = regexp(text_in_file,'\n','split');
% number of genes in the rows
A = cellfun(@(x) numel(regexp(x, '\t')), rows);
% row indices with two genes
two_word_rows = find(A==2); 
% first genes
first_words = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x, '\S+', 'match', 'once'), rows(two_word_rows), 'UniformOutput' , false);

% modifying the rows
for i=setdiff(1:numel(rows), two_word_rows) % exclude the two gene rows
    last_idx = find(two_word_rows<i,1,'last'); % which word to add?
    rows{i} = sprintf('%s\t%s', char(first_words(last_idx)), rows{i});
end

% writing to the file
fid = fopen('newfile.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s', rows{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Do not just copy and paste the code please. Try to go through it, read the comments and check out the documentation of the used functions.

Comment: I tried your code! but you know, as i said the text is very large and have many cases when rows have 2 columns and the next rows had only one column i share the file plz check it

Comment: bro, my file have a gene and its neighbors, ilts like one gene have many neighbors and so because there are so many genes in the rows that having 2 genes means this gene1its first neighbors is gene 2 and then list the other neighbors in the next lines

Comment: the second code have an error: Undefined function 'strsplit' for input arguments of
type 'char'.

Error in Neighbors_network (line 13)
rows = strsplit(text_in_file,'\n');

Comment: what is your matlab version? If I download your file from google drive and run the code, it works perfectly. I have 2015a

Comment: I have avoided `strsplit` in the edited version, you can try now

Answer (score 1):

This code imports all 32491 gene names and then writes them to a new file.

```
oldfile='file.txt';
newfile='file2.txt';
fclose all;
fid=fopen(oldfile,'r');
genes={};
l=fgetl(fid);
while ~isnumeric(l)
    l = regexp(l, '\W', 'split');
    l = l(~cellfun(@isempty,l));
    if ~isempty(l)
        genes(end+1:end+numel(l))=l;
    end
    l=fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);

fid=fopen(newfile,'wt');
for ct = 2:numel(genes)
    fprintf(fid,'%s %s\n',genes{1},genes{ct});
end
fclose(fid);
```

output:

```
TGM1 HIST1H4C
TGM1 HIST1H4B
TGM1 HIST1H4A
TGM1 TGM3
TGM1 HIST1H4G
TGM1 HIST1H4F
TGM1 HIST1H4E
TGM1 HIST1H4D
TGM1 HIST1H4K
TGM1 HIST1H4J
(etc.)
```

Comment: Vahe Tsjitoyan's approach is more elegant. Understand what he does in the regexprep and improve on it so it works on your file. `\s+` matches whitespaces. So if you change `[\n\r]+` into `[\n\r\s]+` it probably already works.

Comment: I think OP needs to clarify what he wants to achieve when there are multiple rows with 2 genes...

Comment: @ Vahe Tshitoyan multiple rows with 2 genes means genes has an gene1a a sirst neighbor and then other genes........gene6 and gene 7 gene 8 means gene 8 is the neighbour of gene 7 and list of other nighbours

Comment: every gene shows its first neighbor  in the same row and its next  neighbors list in the next rows till another rows start and also new gene and its first neighbor in the same line and its other neighbors down and so on

Comment: ok @F.caren so I understood you correctly. Confirm my edit then to your question because that will make things more clear. I have also updated my answer to remove `strsplit`

Comment: @ Vahe Tshitoyan, a little issue in your code, I see at the end of the new file, a row with single gene is added without any neighbor and actually is just a repetition, I mean if gene 1 have gene2, gene 3 to gene6 as neighbors at the end the gene 6 is shown 2 times

Comment: @F.caren I believe that is because you have an empty row at the end of the file. You can just remove the last row before you write to the file using `rows(A==0)=[];`